# checkbox with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

**Situation**

I have a grid with a lot of information. At the beginning of every new line there's a checkbox.

**Aim**

Click on a checkbox and it will be checked. Click on the same checkbox again and it will still be clicked, however the icon is different. Once you click a third time onto the box it will go into unchecked.

**Problem**

I am able to do get the checkbox checked and unchecked, however I don't know how to only change the icon after my checkbox is already checked.

Let's take [this as an example](https://jsfiddle.net/m7o1s5hw/).
In the example only `input type="checkbox"` is used and not the whole grid. It would be an overkill for the question.

How would I go from unckecked (green background) -> checked 1 (red) and then -> checked 2 (random color)?

I might imagine this to be a simple and noobish task, but I'm kinda struggling with it.

Comment: A checkbox is either on or off...there is no "checked again" status. You need to re-think.

Comment: Isn't there a way around?

Comment: Does it need to be a check box? Seems like a candidate for a button.

Comment: Actually checkbox can have a third state (at least visually) - Indeterminate state. See https://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `:indeterminate` CSS pseudo-class selector to style your checkbox while it was in indeterminate state as you asked.

Reference Link: https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/indeterminate/

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to create a custom checkbox, refer to the following page
[How to create custom checkbox](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp)

Then, add your custom js to that custom checkbox. Hope this help